# Hibernate the effective way to persist parent-child data

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following entities and I would like to give some additional thoughts before I make a final decision.

Post

```
@Entity
public class Post {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;
private String author;
private String content;
private String title;

@OneToMany
private List<Comment> comments;

// Standard getters and setters...
```

}

And the entity, which holds child rows

```
@Entity
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String author;
    private String content;

    @ManyToOne
    private Post post;

    // Standard getters and setters...
}
```

A post could have a big number of comments, the most of them of course are not changed during the user session. I would like to find out the best way to save data in the following scenarios:
1. Post data is not changed;
2. Post data is changed.

The standard way is to use the following code

```
Post saved = postRepository.save(post);
```

But is this approach the most effective when you have only one comment added or changed to the post? Should the approach be different here, namely remove the one to many relationship between Post and Comment entities and treat them separately? Also, I don't like the idea that a post object, which needs to be updated in the database, may contain a large number of comments, which in turn adds additional load on network.

Answer (score 0):

First to make that work you need a cascade in the post entity else it will just update/save the Post entity

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,mappedBy = "post")
private List<Comment> comments;
```

Also hibernate works by dirty checking your entity.

Hibernate during the merge(update) will dirty check your managed entities and generate one update query just for the entities that you changed, so if you don't touch the `Post` entity and just update one `Comment` hibernate will generate one update query.

Also this phrase make no sense.

> Also, I don't like the idea that a post object, which needs to be
>   updated in the database, may contain a large number of comments, which
>   in turn adds additional load on network.

The `OneToMany` relationship specified in `Post` is just for hibernate convenience and it's actually optional.
With that you define what is called a bi-directional relationship.

There is nothing in db except for the fk on `Comment` referencing `Post`